# Targeting nested content in Xaml displayed using ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

Consider the following usercontrol:

[image: Filter Pane Control]

This is a custom usercontrol that I have written that has two nested elements.

**FilterContent** displays a special type of markup that filters content on the right hand side of the screen

**MainContent** hosts the filtered content.

The only real purpose of the control is to provide consistent UI and animation across the application, as this filter/content pattern is used frequently.

The (simplified) Xaml of the usercontrol look as follows:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"  Content="{Binding ElementName=filterControl, Path=FilterControl}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding ElementName=filterControl, Path=MainControl}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
```

The codebehind is :

```
public sealed partial class FilterPaneControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty FilterControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FilterControl", typeof(object), typeof(FilterPaneControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(object), PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static DependencyProperty MainControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MainControl", typeof (object), typeof (FilterPaneControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public FilterPaneControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object FilterControl
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(FilterControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public object MainControl
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(MainControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainControlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The usage of the control in an implementing page is :

```
    <Generic:FilterPaneControl>
        <Generic:FilterPaneControl.FilterControl>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Filter Content here"/>
            </Grid>
        </Generic:FilterPaneControl.FilterControl>
        <Generic:FilterPaneControl.MainControl>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Main Content here"/>
            </Grid>
        </Generic:FilterPaneControl.MainControl>
    </Generic:FilterPaneControl>
```

That works fine!

**The Problem**

The problem is when I then want to reference some of the content within the control from the implementing page. A good case for this is visual states for handling snap/portrait (WinRT implementation)

[image]

```
    <Generic:FilterPaneControl>
        <Generic:FilterPaneControl.FilterControl>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Name="filterContent1"  Text="Filter Content here"/>
            </Grid>
        </Generic:FilterPaneControl.FilterControl>
        <Generic:FilterPaneControl.MainControl>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Main Content here"/>
            </Grid>
        </Generic:FilterPaneControl.MainControl>
    </Generic:FilterPaneControl>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="filterContent1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

This leads to a run-time exception, as the visualstatemanager cannot find the referenced element 'filterContent1' even though it exists in the Visual Tree. 
Additionally, if I try and reference the element directly in an Page.Loaded event handler, filterContent1 is null.

It is as if the nested Xaml doesn't render until later - which is throwing the visualstatemanager too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First, `VisualStateManager` should be placed in a single panel with the element for which it is done, otherwise it would be an *exception*. For your case it turns out like this:

```
<Generic:FilterPaneControl>
    <Generic:FilterPaneControl.FilterControl>
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="filterContent1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <TextBlock x:Name="filterContent1" Text="Filter Content here"/>
        </Grid>
    </Generic:FilterPaneControl.FilterControl>

    ...
```

Second, usually `VisualStateManager` placed in either a `Template / Style`, or `UserControl`. The transition to the states is carried out either in code or through XAML (with special techniques). Sample of set state behind code:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(NameOfControl, "State1", true);
```

Third, in a manner:

```
<Storyboard>
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="filterContent1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

`Width` not sets, in my case is an exception. We need to use animation something like this:

```
<Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="filterContent1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
    <DoubleAnimation To="200" Duration="0:0:1.0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

As proof of his words, I give an example:

`MainWindow`

```
<Window x:Class="VSMinUserControlHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VSMinUserControlHelp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="Control1" Height="118" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50,12,101,0" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Name="State1Button" Width="75" Click="State1Button_Click">State1</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }

    private void State1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control1, "State1", true);
    }
}
```

`UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="VSMinUserControlHelp.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d"              
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common1">
                <VisualState x:Name="State1">
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="filterContent1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="200" Duration="0:0:1.0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <TextBlock x:Name="filterContent1" Background="Aqua" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Filter Content here"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`Note:` Example run on VS 2010, Windows XP, not *tested* under WinRT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have thought about your solution before, but was reluctant to implement it as although it potentially solves the VisualStateManager issue, it still doesn't solve other scenarios when I wish to reference elements within the child content from the parent container. (referencing child elements in Page.Load are null!)
I'll give it a go today though to at least try and solve the VSM problem.